# get index of word in english dictionary :Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, indexing, words

I want to know index of a word in English dictionary .I would like to know if there is any python library and API could be helpful for the same .
Thank you so much if you are reading this question .

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try PyDictionary 1.3.4.

```
pip install PyDictionary
```

[enter link description here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDictionary/1.3.4)

Comment: @Achilies,  I didn't get API to find index of word in English dictionary .
example : int index = getWordIndex("a"); will return 1 .

Comment: You should read the documentation to get a good knowledge about how to implement the functions to get the desired output.